# grep particular string from directory in Unix

Tags: unix, grep

I have list of compressed files in a directory /var/log/bb e.g. console.log.1.xz, console.log.2.xz etc. I would like to grep a particular string from these files in a single command. Any ideas on how to achieve this

I have been trying like this

```
sudo xzcat /var/log/bb | grep 'string'
```

Comment: In `grep 'string'` you aren't greping a string, you're grepping a regexp so naming it `string` is misleading at best. You should either write `grep 'regexp'` or `grep -F 'string'`, whichever it is you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find`

```
find /var/log/bb -iname '*.xz' -type f -exec grep 'string' {} +
```

Using `grep`

```
$ grep 'string' /var/log/bb/*.xz
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting:

```
grep -l 'string' $(find /var/log/bb -type f -name "*.xz")
```